# Passing Async State to Next.js Component via Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, use-state

I'm fetching WordPress posts asynchronously via `getStaticProps()`...

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params, preview = false, previewData }) {
    const data = await getPostsByCategory(params.slug, preview, previewData)
    return {
        props: {
            preview,
            posts: data?.posts
        },
    }
}
```

... and passing them to `useState`:

```
const [filteredArticles, setFilteredArticles] = useState(posts?.edges)
```

Then, I pass the state to a component:

```
router.isFallback ? (
    // If we're still fetching data...
    <div>Loading…</div>
) : (
    <ArticleGrid myArticles={filteredArticles} />
```

This is necessary because another component will `setFilteredArticles` with a filter function.

But when we are passing the state to `ArticlesGrid`, the data is not ready when the component loads. This is confusing to me since we passing the state within a `router.isFallback` condition.

Even if we set state within `useEffect`...

```
const [filteredArticles, setFilteredArticles] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredArticles(posts)
}, [posts?.edges])
```

... the data arrives too late for the component.

I'm new to Next.js. I can probably hack my way through this, but I assume there's an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at some `useEffect` examples:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Hello there");
});
```

This `useEffect` is executed **after the first render** and on each subsequent rerender.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Hello there once");
}, []);
```

This `useEffect` is executed only once, **after the first render**.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Hello there when id changes");
}, [props.id]);
```

This `useEffect` is executed **after the first render**, every time *props.id* changes.

Some possible solutions to your problem:

**No articles case**

You probably want to treat this case in your ArticleGrid component anyway, in order to prevent any potential errors.

In ArticleGrid.js:

```
const {myArticles} = props;

if(!myArticles) {
    return (<div>Your custom no data component... </div>);
}

// normal logic
return ...
```

Alternatively, you could also treat this case in the parent component:

```
{
  router.isFallback ? (
    // If we're still fetching data...
    <div>Loading…</div>
  ) : (
    <>
      {
        filteredArticles
          ? <ArticleGrid myArticles={filteredArticles} />
          : <div>Your custom no data component... </div>
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

**Use initial props**

Send the initial props in case the filteres haven't been set:

```
const myArticles = filteredArticles || posts?.edges;
```

and then:

```
<ArticleGrid myArticles={myArticles} />
```